# “The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form” in Symfony3

Tags: php, forms, symfony, kubernetes, csrf

I have a Symfony 3 application, which is deployed via Kubernetes. There is a page which has 2 forms and 2 datatables tables with server side processing. I am using Redis for session storage. I randomly get the error "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form" when submitting either form. If I have any combination of only 2 (2 forms, 0 tables, 1 form, 1 table; 0 forms, 2 tables) I don't get the error. Token is sent with every form submission.

Could someone please provide some hint as to what could be the reason? 
I already tried the solutions to the similar questions on Stackoverflow, but to no avail.

Edit:

I just noticed that when the CSRF error occurs I don't see sf_redirect in the cookies. All successful calls have this cookie.

Update:

I found a solution. I updated my firewall config.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        stateless: true
```

Before it was `stateless: false`

Answer (score 0):

To be sure the CSRF is on your form, you can add with `{{ form_rest(form) }}` but if you are on dev mode, maybe it's because you are not in https ?

Comment: The token is always sent, but is invalid